# Connection String for MySQL (C# in asp.net)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, odbc, connection-string

I am using a the C# ODBC object in asp.net to connect up to a MySQL server hosted on another computer (on the same network).

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Odbc" %>
<html>
<body>
<script language="C#" runat="server">

protected void Page_Load(Object Src, EventArgs E) 
{
try
{
using(OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.51.30 Driver};Database=test;Server=192.168.1.109;UID=Username;PWD=Password;"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using(OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM tablename", connection))
    using(OdbcDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(dr.Read())
            Response.Write(dr["name"].ToString() + "<br>");
        dr.Close();
    }
    connection.Close();
}
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
Response.Write("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am currently getting this error when I run the code:

```
An error occurred: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

I am hosting this on a  Microsoft IIS server, with ASP.net enabled. Would I be able to get any help with fixing this error?

Link to image of my MySQL server: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NYCr.png

Comment: Please see below link for MySQL http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Answer (score 0):

> Would I be able to get any help with fixing this error?

Yes, you would. So, your only question was answered. And now? Please think a little more about WHAT you ask.

TO your problem.

Like always, http://www.connectionstrings.com/ is the primary resource for this ;) Anything you ever wanted to know about connectionstrings on one place.

For MySQL (asuming 5.2) you can find (for ODBC) the solution at:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-2/

Now, your string looks good - so I start assuming you have a driver problem. I would assume that wherever you run it it just does not have - the ODBC ddriver installed.

THAT SAID: there is no real reason to use ODBC (which has native prerequisites) and not a (managed) MySQL Driver?

if you really miss the ODBC driver, you can ind the downloads at http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/. But I would really not use ODBC here - not with a native connector available.

Answer (score 0):

I think you better use `MySQlConnection` as well as `MyqlCommand` for your needs:
eg:

```
 server = "localhost";
        database = "connectcsharptomysql";
        uid = "username";
        password = "password";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + 
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```